# Java: why TimeUnit have missing enums?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, time

I just wonder, why some enums are missing on the TimeUnit class of Java?

Actually the max timeunit is DAY while i would like to use stuff like WEEK, YEAR...

Comment: Where is the limit? What about fortnights? Jubilees? Zettaseconds?

Comment: Also given that a year is not constant, it would not be a good fit. Since the documented usage of the class is _mainly used to inform time-based methods_, anything beyond a day is probably unreasonable for the intended usage.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `TimeUnit.DAYS` constant represents an interval of 24 hours, not a *calendar day* (midnight to midnight). Anything beyond a day (a week, a month, a year) is a calendar unit, not a time unit. The duration of calendar units depends on the calendar in use: for example, a week can be longer or shorter by an hour on weeks when daylight savings time goes in and out of effect, leap years are longer by a day, and so on. That is why including calendar units into `TimeUnit` enumeration would not make sense.

Comment: Java 8 provides [java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) which may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 ChronoUnit was introduced, you have in one enum all the usual time units between NANOS (nanoseconds) and CENTURIES, MILLENIA, and even FOREVER: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html
(cf. also Julien Kronegg's comment to the chosen answer)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: It's javadoc, if it disappears it means that java is not used anymore. If the particular link disappears, then it's easy to find the new link with a simple google search. I think my answer is clear enough already.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know that. Please do it your own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186493/discussion-between-gismo-ranas-and-double-beep).